# GVim: Shift + Insert dump <S-Insert> instead of the clipboard text

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.10, gvim

While editing inside gVIM, whenever I press Shift+Insert, it's insert the <S-Insert> text.
I'm running on Ubuntu Maverick and compile Vim from source.
This is really annoying. What's wrong with my VIM?

Answer (score 5):

I've found out that <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Insert</kbd> does not work in gVim if `:set paste` is active. Instead of inserting the clipboard contents, it will insert the text "`<S-Insert>`". Normal (console) vim does not suffer from this problem, probably because shift-insert is a terminal thing in that case, and not something handled by Vim.

The solution for me was to turn off paste mode: `:set nopaste`.